# How to get a URL address without IP or hostname using javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope to get a URL address without IP or hostname such as

```
image.htm?diskindex=0&diskcount=2&sortby=0&view=0&imagefilter=1&sizemore=1
```

but `window.location.href` return the following result.

```
http://192.168.0.149:9031/image.htm?diskindex=0&diskcount=2&sortby=0&view=0&imagefilter=1&sizemore=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this.Use `split()` method which splits your string into array.

```js
    var url ='http://192.168.0.149:9031/image.htm?diskindex=0&diskcount=2&sortby=0&view=0&imagefilter=1&sizemore=1';//window.location.href
    
    var path = url.split('/');
    alert(path[3]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `pathname` property

```js
window.location.pathname
```

Comment: Thanks!  but window.location.pathname only return image.htm ! I hope to return image.htm?diskindex=0&diskcount=2&sortby=0&view=0&imagefilter=1&sizemore=1

Comment: @HelloCW `window.location.pathname + window.location.search`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `URL` constructor, or `location` `.pathname` and `.search`

```js
var loc = "http://192.168.0.149:9031/image.htm?diskindex=0&diskcount=2&sortby=0&view=0&imagefilter=1&sizemore=1";

var url = new URL(loc);

var pathSearch = url.pathname.slice(1) + url.search;

console.log(pathSearch);
```